# Explanation of the last scene in Blue Jay (2016)

Tags: plot-explanation, ending, blue-jay

In *[Blue Jay (2016)](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt3574352/)* directed by Michael Ciulla, what does the guy tell the woman at the end of the movie which causes the woman to realize that it was about a bird (as I guess) called Blue Jay? Is it implied that the woman now becomes a part of that gang?

Comment: Agreed. Confused. She gave up? I need others opinions and insight.

Answer (score 1):

I got the impression she went nuts, had a heart attack, died... Because she was with all the dead ppl except the waitress, so she was hallucinating if she didn't die... She had suffered ALOT of physical and mental extremes the past few days and shock set in. In my opinion she died.
Not the ending I would have made after female surviving.....